# On Windows with Python and pypyodbc how do you list the drivers available?

Tags: python, pypyodbc

For a python script that is shared by many people I need a solution to detect the users driver so I can dynamically construct the connection string. I'm currently using the os environment COMPUTERNAME like:

```
if os.environ['COMPUTERNAME'] == 'MattsDesktop':
print("You are using: Oracle 12")
    self.DataConnectOracle = 'DRIVER={Oracle in 12cR1client32bit};SERVER=Xyz;DBQ=DEVenv;UID=AllDev;PWD=Secret2Secret'
```

But this has to be updated whenever a user makes a change. Seems like I should be able to get their driver info and not have to maintain these if's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it won't give you the exact *version* of the driver, `pypyodbc.drivers()` will give you the *name* of the drivers available to it on Windows. That should suffice since you only need the driver name (not the version) in order to construct the connection string.

For example, on my machine

```python
import pypyodbc
drivers_list = sorted(pypyodbc.drivers())
for driver_name in drivers_list:
    print(driver_name)
```

prints

```
Driver da Microsoft para arquivos texto (*.txt; *.csv)
Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb)
Driver do Microsoft Excel(*.xls)
Driver do Microsoft Paradox (*.db )
Driver do Microsoft dBase (*.dbf)
Driver para o Microsoft Visual FoxPro
Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)
Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)
Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)
Microsoft Access dBASE Driver (*.dbf, *.ndx, *.mdx)
Microsoft Access-Treiber (*.mdb)
Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)
Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)
Microsoft Excel-Treiber (*.xls)
Microsoft FoxPro VFP Driver (*.dbf)
Microsoft ODBC for Oracle
Microsoft Paradox Driver (*.db )
Microsoft Paradox-Treiber (*.db )
Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)
Microsoft Text-Treiber (*.txt; *.csv)
Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver
Microsoft Visual FoxPro-Treiber
Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)
Microsoft dBase VFP Driver (*.dbf)
Microsoft dBase-Treiber (*.dbf)
MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver
MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver
ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server
SQL Server
SQL Server Native Client 11.0
SQLite3 ODBC Driver
```

For a list of just the Oracle drivers, I can use

```python
oracle_list = [x for x in pypyodbc.drivers() if "Oracle" in x]
```

Comment: Perfection! Especially that little line of code: sqlserver_list = [x for x in pypyodbc.drivers() if "SQL Server Native Client " in x] , just like yours!! THANKS!!!